# How to plot markers when a variable=1 or use 'axvspan' to highlight regions when a variable=1

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts, markers

We have EURUSD data from 2 price feeds as shown below (100 row sample)

## Data

```py
Date,sell_A,buy_A,sell_B,buy_B,buy_B_sell_A,mispricing_1,exploitable_1,buy_A_sell_B,mispricing_2,exploitable_2,Time
2020-01-01 22:51:41.368,1.12144,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-26.999999999999247,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:41.368000
2020-01-01 22:51:41.978,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:41.978000
2020-01-01 22:51:43.189,1.12147,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:43.189000
2020-01-01 22:51:43.731,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:43.731000
2020-01-01 22:51:57.360,1.12137,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:57.360000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.022,1.1213600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.022000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.024,1.12151,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.024000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.189,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.189000
2020-01-01 22:52:18.720,1.12142,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:18.720000
2020-01-01 22:52:20.066,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:20.066000
2020-01-01 22:52:42.802,1.12148,1.1217700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:42.802000
2020-01-01 22:52:42.972,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:42.972000
2020-01-01 22:52:45.320,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:45.320000
2020-01-01 22:52:45.489,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:45.489000
2020-01-01 22:53:01.489,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:01.489000
2020-01-01 22:53:20.940,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:20.940000
2020-01-01 22:53:22.823,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:22.823000
2020-01-01 22:53:22.826,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:22.826000
2020-01-01 22:53:26.589,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:26.589000
2020-01-01 22:53:27.929,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:27.929000
2020-01-01 22:53:28.895,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:28.895000
2020-01-01 22:53:38.038,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:38.038000
2020-01-01 22:53:39.027,1.12147,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:39.027000
2020-01-01 22:53:39.244,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:39.244000
2020-01-01 22:53:51.144,1.1213600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:51.144000
2020-01-01 22:53:58.096,1.1213799999999998,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:58.096000
2020-01-01 22:54:03.460,1.1214899999999999,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:03.460000
2020-01-01 22:54:05.330,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:05.330000
2020-01-01 22:54:21.404,1.1213799999999998,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:21.404000
2020-01-01 22:54:22.852,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:22.852000
2020-01-01 22:54:23.080,1.12145,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:23.080000
2020-01-01 22:54:40.278,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:40.278000
2020-01-01 22:54:41.143,1.12143,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:41.143000
2020-01-01 22:54:42.898,1.12145,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:42.898000
2020-01-01 22:54:47.548,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:47.548000
2020-01-01 22:55:05.642,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:05.642000
2020-01-01 22:55:30.874,1.12133,1.12176,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:30.874000
2020-01-01 22:55:40.157,1.12132,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:40.157000
2020-01-01 22:55:41.599,1.12133,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:41.599000
2020-01-01 22:55:42.564,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:42.564000
2020-01-01 22:56:12.622,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:12.622000
2020-01-01 22:56:12.945,1.12144,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:12.945000
2020-01-01 22:56:28.780,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:28.780000
2020-01-01 22:57:07.971,1.12145,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:07.971000
2020-01-01 22:57:27.648,1.12135,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:27.648000
2020-01-01 22:57:29.527,1.12133,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:29.527000
2020-01-01 22:57:30.644,1.12134,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:30.644000
2020-01-01 22:57:30.646,1.12143,1.1216700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:30.646000
2020-01-01 22:57:47.624,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:47.624000
2020-01-01 22:58:25.640,1.12144,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:25.640000
2020-01-01 22:58:29.615,1.12143,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:29.615000
2020-01-01 22:58:51.560,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:51.560000
2020-01-01 22:59:24.612,1.12142,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:24.612000
2020-01-01 22:59:40.937,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:40.937000
2020-01-01 22:59:50.980,1.12135,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:50.980000
2020-01-01 22:59:52.092,1.12131,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:52.092000
2020-01-01 22:59:52.525,1.12135,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:52.525000
2020-01-01 22:59:57.627,1.12135,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:57.627000
2020-01-01 22:59:58.951,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:58.951000
2020-01-01 23:00:00.366,1.12141,1.12164,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:00.366000
2020-01-01 23:00:03.068,1.12142,1.1216700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:03.068000
2020-01-01 23:00:04.847,1.1214600000000001,1.12162,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:04.847000
2020-01-01 23:00:06.084,1.1214600000000001,1.12164,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:06.084000
2020-01-01 23:00:19.153,1.1213899999999999,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:19.153000
2020-01-01 23:00:20.209,1.12147,1.12165,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:20.209000
2020-01-01 23:00:24.538,1.1215,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:24.538000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.054,1.12152,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.054000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.236,1.1214899999999999,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.236000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.738,1.1214899999999999,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.738000
2020-01-01 23:00:26.257,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:26.257000
2020-01-01 23:00:26.259,1.1214899999999999,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:26.259000
2020-01-01 23:00:27.074,1.12154,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:27.074000
2020-01-01 23:00:28.086,1.12154,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:28.086000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.206,1.1215600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.206000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.376,1.1215899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.376000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.429,1.1215899999999999,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.429000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.723,1.1215899999999999,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.723000
2020-01-01 23:00:32.376,1.1215899999999999,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:32.376000
2020-01-01 23:00:32.823,1.1216,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:32.823000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.094,1.1216,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.094000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.313,1.12161,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.313000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.316,1.12162,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.316000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.317,1.12162,1.12176,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.317000
2020-01-01 23:00:36.054,1.12161,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:36.054000
2020-01-01 23:00:37.001,1.12162,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:37.001000
2020-01-01 23:00:37.055,1.12161,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:37.055000
2020-01-01 23:00:40.232,1.12161,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:40.232000
2020-01-01 23:00:45.904,1.12161,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:45.904000
2020-01-01 23:00:48.687,1.12163,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:48.687000
2020-01-01 23:00:48.864,1.12164,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:48.864000
2020-01-01 23:00:49.186,1.12164,1.12173,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:49.186000
2020-01-01 23:00:50.347,1.12164,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:50.347000
2020-01-01 23:00:58.893,1.12166,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:58.893000
2020-01-01 23:00:59.591,1.12166,1.12173,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:59.591000
2020-01-01 23:01:01.089,1.12166,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:01.089000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.094,1.12168,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.094000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.097,1.12171,1.1218,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.097000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.100,1.12173,1.12188,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.100000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.104,1.1217700000000002,1.122,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.104000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.158,1.1217700000000002,1.12204,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.158000
```

We have plotted variables 'buy_A' and 'sell_B' on a graph, shown below using this code;

## Code to plot EURUSD chart

```py
plt.figure(figsize=[20,7])
plt.plot(data.Date, data.buy_A, 'r', label='Buy_A')
plt.plot(df.Date, df.sell_B, 'b', label='Sell_B')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.title("Buy A Sell B Graph")
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

[image]

We now want to plot markers on this chart when 'exploitable_1==1'. 'exploitable_1' = 1 when the difference between 'buy_A' and 'sell_B' >6.

We looked into using the axvspan function to highlight multiple vertical columns for all the areas where 'exploitable_1==1' and also want to use markers but not sure how to do either.